# does the c preprocessor handle floating point math constants

Tags: c

Say that I have

```
   #define A 23.9318;
   #define B 0.330043;
   #define C 5.220628;
```

I want to do

```
const unsigned result =  (unsigned)(0x01000000 * ( A * B / C ));    // unsigned is 32 bit
```

What I hope for is to have result with fixed decimal representation of the floating point calculations.

I cannot pre combine A,B,C together as their definition is not part of my code and I need
it to work if they are changed.

Comment: In most of the cases it's not a good idea to end a `#define` with a semicolon.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It's not that way in the code. Mostly I am asking about the precision of the result. Will the C preprocessor do the A B  C part in float all the way up to the cast.

Comment: The pre-processor will simply replace `A` with `23.9318;` and `B` with ... - and so on.

Comment: I see your point. My problem is that my team lead said our compiler doesn't do floating point math yet there are statements like this many places.  If everything is being cast to integer the results would be wrong.

Comment: In addition to what @alk said about not using `;` at the end of your #defines (which in this case will cause an error in your `const` statement)  you are feeding your floating point evaluation into an unsigned type, which is not going to allow _result_ to contain the desired result.  Use:  `const float result =...` instead.

Comment: My compiler does not support floating point. So I have to represent this value in fixed point as best I can.  I was just told by another that the preprocessor will resolve all these A B C into a value.  I think we are using GCC.  Anyway thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the standard C preprocessor operations do not perform floating-point arithmetic.

A C implementation is permitted, but not required, by the C standard to perform these operations at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

The following illustrates that although not required, some C implementations do include compile-time computations of floating point...

The following code was compiled using a C99 implementation and produced the indicated results (commented value in `main()`:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

#define A 23.9318
#define B 0.330043
#define C 5.220628

#define result A*B/C  //1.512945007267325

const unsigned resultB = (unsigned)result*(0x01000000);

int main(void)
{
    resultB; //24394701
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want.  I guess I will just make some test code and get the correct answer I will run with it regardless of who is doing the floating point part.  Thanks

Comment: I am surprised that minGW does not do compile-time computations.  It is fairly progressive in many other features...(eg range case for switch statements, etc)  Good luck

Comment: Yes, GCC does, but not for comparisons. So `#if result < 10` will not compile.

Comment: @automorphic Because the computation is done after preprocessing.

Comment: @Rainald62 Yes, good point - it's a compiler feature - not a preprocessor improvement.