# How to compare float value by preprocessor ? It is failing to compare float values

Tags: c, floating-point, comparison, c-preprocessor, precision

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#define a 4.5
int main()  
{  
    #if a==4.5 
        printf("Correct\n");
    #endif
    return 0;  
}
```

It is failing to compare float values.

Comment: does this is the answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241031/does-the-c-preprocessor-handle-floating-point-math-constants

Comment: _It is failing to compare float values._ -- Yes, Expressions in the `#if` prepricessor directive must have integral values, see the [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/preprocessor/hash-if-hash-elif-hash-else-and-hash-endif-directives-c-cpp?view=vs-2019) and [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/cpp/If.html) documentation.

Comment: @MOehm It's neither MS nor GCC that set the rules. It's the C standard, in this case I think chapter 6.10.1 (and referred from it, 6.6) is relevant.

Comment: @thebusybee: Yes, but my links aren't about setting the rules, they are about documenting them. I found these links easily and so I linked them. I'll leave the hair-splitting to you standard lawyers.

Comment: @MOehm ;-) Setting the rules is just one thing, how it is in RL is another. Especially MS is kind of ... erm, creative ... about C.

Comment: I agree that MS's support of the C standard is not exactly high, but here gcc, MS and the standard (as far as I know) seem to agree for once.

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthan no.