# A little bit confused with using conditional compilation

Tags: c

While I was learning the concept of conditional compilation, i encountered some problems.
I was trying to define a Symbolic constant and change its value if the value wasn't something i expected. And facing some errors

SO this is the code

```
// Demonstrating conditional compilation

#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14

int main()
{
    #if (PI==3.14)
        printf("Correct value!");
    #else
        #undef PI
        #define PI 3.14
        printf("Correct value assigned!");
    #endif
}
```

and this is the error(s)

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "/home/karthik/karthik/Learning-C-Lang/Learning_C/10. Preprocessor/Preprocessor DIrectives/programs/programs/conditional_compilation_demo.c" -o "/home/karthik/karthik/Learning-C-Lang/Learning_C/Misc/Binaries (compiled on Linux)/Binaries/conditional_compilation_demo"
/home/karthik/karthik/Learning-C-Lang/Learning_C/10. Preprocessor/Preprocessor DIrectives/programs/programs/conditional_compilation_demo.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/karthik/karthik/Learning-C-Lang/Learning_C/10. Preprocessor/Preprocessor DIrectives/programs/programs/conditional_compilation_demo.c:4:12: error: floating constant in preprocessor expression
    4 | #define PI 3.14
      |            ^~~~
/home/karthik/karthik/Learning-C-Lang/Learning_C/10. Preprocessor/Preprocessor DIrectives/programs/programs/conditional_compilation_demo.c:8:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘PI’
    8 |     #if (PI==3.14)
      |          ^~
/home/karthik/karthik/Learning-C-Lang/Learning_C/10. Preprocessor/Preprocessor DIrectives/programs/programs/conditional_compilation_demo.c:8:14: error: floating constant in preprocessor expression
    8 |     #if (PI==3.14)
      |              ^~~~

Build finished with error(s).
```

But this code works

```
// Write a program to calculate the area of a circle. Make a symbolic constant for PI.

#include <stdio.h>

// Define a symbolic constant PI
// It is a convention to name symbolic constants in uppercase
#define PI 3.14 

int main()
{
    int r;
    printf("Enter radius: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Area = %f", PI*r*r);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [does the c preprocessor handle floating point math constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241031/does-the-c-preprocessor-handle-floating-point-math-constants)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560357/can-the-c-preprocessor-perform-integer-arithmetic):

> You can do integer arithmetic with the C pre-processor; you cannot do floating point arithmetic with it.

Apparently, the C preprocessor does not allow floating constants in conditional operators.

Comment: Thanks man you helped me a lot! God bless u